# Create instance of Eq and calculation

Tags: class, haskell

I have a class for `Rechner`and `Eq`. `Rechner` is for the calculation. And with `Eq` I want to check the equality.

```hs
data Ausdruck a = Zahl1 a | Add1 (Ausdruck a) (Ausdruck a)

class Rechner a where
  rechnen :: a -> Double

class Eq a where
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool

instance Rechner (Ausdruck Double) where
  rechnen (Zahl1 a) = a
  rechnen (Add1 zahl1 zahl2) = rechnen(zahl1) + rechnen(zahl2)

instance Prelude.Eq a => Aufgabe.Eq(Ausdruck a) where
  (Zahl1 a) == (Zahl1 b) = a Prelude.== b
  (Add1 a1 a2) == (Add1 b1 b2) = rechnen(Add1 a1 a2) Aufgabe.== rechnen(Add1 b1 b2)
  _ == _ = False



isEqual :: Prelude.Eq a => Ausdruck a -> Ausdruck a -> Bool
isEqual l1 l2 = l1 Aufgabe.== l2

firstNum = (Add1(Zahl1 1.5)(Zahl1 2.5))
secondNum = (Add1(Zahl1 2.5)(Zahl1 1.5))
call = isEqual firstNum secondNum
```

But I always get some errors.

```
• Could not deduce (Rechner (Ausdruck a))
        arising from a use of ‘rechnen’
      from the context: Prelude.Eq a
        bound by the instance declaration
• In the first argument of ‘(Aufgabe.==)’, namely
        ‘rechnen (Add1 a1 a2)’
      In the expression:
        rechnen (Add1 a1 a2) Aufgabe.== rechnen (Add1 b1 b2)
      In an equation for ‘Aufgabe.==’:
          (Add1 a1 a2) Aufgabe.== (Add1 b1 b2)
            = rechnen (Add1 a1 a2) Aufgabe.== rechnen (Add1 b1 b2)

• Could not deduce (Aufgabe.Eq Double)
        arising from a use of ‘Aufgabe.==’
      from the context: Prelude.Eq a
        bound by the instance declaration

 • In the expression:
        rechnen (Add1 a1 a2) Aufgabe.== rechnen (Add1 b1 b2)
      In an equation for ‘Aufgabe.==’:
          (Add1 a1 a2) Aufgabe.== (Add1 b1 b2)
            = rechnen (Add1 a1 a2) Aufgabe.== rechnen (Add1 b1 b2)
      In the instance declaration for ‘Aufgabe.Eq (Ausdruck a)’
```

Comment: Why do you create an `Eq` class?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am supposed to define type "Ausdruck" as an instance of class `Eq` and override the `(==)`function for comparing 'Ausdrucke`

Comment: @zeppal: well you then use the one from `Prelude`, not define a new *typeclass*, only a new instance for the existing one.

Comment: You write `instance Prelude.Eq a => Aufgabe.Eq (Ausdruck a) where ...`, which claims that the instance *only* calls methods from `Prelude.Eq`. But your instance actually calls `rechnen` and `Aufgabe.==`, which are not methods from `Prelude.Eq`. This is what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason this happens is because you define a class:

```
class Eq a where
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

This thus means that there are now two `Eq` classes in the scope: the one of the `Prelude`, and the one of your module (`Aufgabe`). There are also two `(==)` functions (one from the `Prelude` and one from the `Augable`). The compiler will thus raise errors each time you use the `(==)` function, since it does not know which of the two to use.

You solve this by using `Aufgabe.==`, but you also do this for `rechnen (…) Aufgabe.== rechnen (…)` which are `Double`s, and there is no instance of `Aufgabe.Eq` for `Double`.

But there is no need at all to introduce the `Eq` typeclass, just work with the existing one:

```
data Ausdruck a = Zahl1 a | Add1 (Ausdruck a) (Ausdruck a)

class Rechner a where
  rechnen :: a -> Double

-- no class Eq!

instance Rechner (Ausdruck Double) where
  rechnen (Zahl1 a) = a
  rechnen (Add1 zahl1 zahl2) = rechnen zahl1 + rechnen zahl2

instance Eq (Ausdruck Double) where
  (Zahl1 a) == (Zahl1 b) = a == b
  (Add1 a1 a2) == (Add1 b1 b2) = rechnen (Add1 a1 a2) == rechnen (Add1 b1 b2)
  _ == _ = False

firstNum, secondNum :: Ausdruck Double
firstNum = Add1 (Zahl1 1.5) (Zahl1 2.5)
secondNum = Add1 (Zahl1 2.5) (Zahl1 1.5)

call = firstNum == secondNum
```

Since your `rechnen` only seems to be defined for an `Ausdruck`, you can define the function *without* a typeclass:

```
-- no class Rechner or instance

rechnen :: Num a => Ausdruck a -> a
rechnen (Zahl1 x) = x
rechnen (Add1 x1 x2) = rechnen x1 + rechnen x2
```

Since we here made it more general to work with any `Num a` type, we can generalize the instance as well to:

```
instance (Eq a, Num a) => Eq (Ausdruck a) where
  (Zahl1 a) == (Zahl1 b) = a == b
  (Add1 a1 a2) == (Add1 b1 b2) = rechnen (Add1 a1 a2) == rechnen (Add1 b1 b2)
```

Comment: I get an error: `• Could not deduce (Rechner (Ausdruck a))
        arising from a use of ‘rechnen’
      from the context: Eq a
        bound by the instance declaration` 
` • In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘rechnen (Add1 a1 a2)’
      In the expression: rechnen (Add1 a1 a2) == rechnen (Add1 b1 b2)
      In an equation for ‘==’:
          (Add1 a1 a2) == (Add1 b1 b2)
            = rechnen (Add1 a1 a2) == rechnen (Add1 b1 b2)`

Comment: @zeppal: since you can only do that for `Rechner (Ausdruck Double)`, you can indeed only do `Eq` checks with `Eq (Ausdruck Double)` as well, since it depends on `rechnen`.

Comment: `firstNum = (Add1 (Zahl1 1.5) (Zahl1 2.5))
secondNum = (Add1 (Zahl1 2.5) (Zahl1 1.5))

isEqual :: Ausdruck Double -> Ausdruck Double -> Bool
isEqual l1 l2 = l1 == l2

call = isEqual firstNum secondNum
`
It's working like this. 
But a call like this `(==) (Zahl 6.5) (Add (Zahl 1.5) (Add (Zahl 3) (Zahl 2)))` gets False instead of True.

Comment: @zeppal: that is because of your implementation of `Eq`: note that it can only give `True` if both operands are `Zah1`, or `Add1`, not when they are mixed. You thus should rewrite the `Eq` instance.

Comment: So I should write every possible variant in the `Eq` instance? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: @zeppal: that can be done, but in fact you don't need to work with pattern matching at `x == y = ...`

Comment: What would be the other variant you are referring to?